# JavaScript method window.open() is not opening new window in my JavaFX browser

Tags: javafx-8

I have built an web browser in JavaFX. I want to add new popup window feature in my browser. when I use JavaScript method window.open(). It will execute code and open new popup window.

```
    package browser;

    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;
    import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
    import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
    import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
    import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.event.EventTarget;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
    import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
    import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
    import javafx.scene.image.Image;
    import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
    import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
    import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
    import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

public class BrowserController implements Initializable {

        @FXML
        BorderPane browserBP;
        @FXML
        WebView browserWV;
        @FXML
        ImageView stopReloadIV;
        @FXML
        TextField addressBarTF;
        @FXML
        ProgressIndicator progressPI;
        @FXML
        Label statusL;



        /**
         * Initializes the controller class.
         */
        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
        { 
            popup pop_up = new popup();
        browserWV.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>()
            {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observable, Worker.State oldValue, Worker.State newValue) {
                    statusL.setText("loading... " + browserWV.getEngine().getLocation());                
                    stopReloadIV.setImage(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/stoploading.png")));
                    progressPI.setVisible(true);
                    if(newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                       // 
                        JSObject window = (JSObject) browserWV.getEngine().executeScript("window");
                        window.setMember("window",pop_up);
                        addressBarTF.setText(browserWV.getEngine().getLocation());
                        statusL.setText("loaded");
                        progressPI.setVisible(false);
                        stopReloadIV.setImage(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/reload.png")));
                        if(browserBP.getParent() != null) {
                            TabPane tp = (TabPane)browserBP.getParent().getParent();                           
                            for(Tab tab : tp.getTabs()) {
                                if(tab.getContent() == browserBP) {
                                    tab.setText(browserWV.getEngine().getTitle());
                                    break;
                                }
                            }                                                
                        }
                    }

                }

            });
            WebEngine webEngine = browserWV.getEngine();
            webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);





        }


    @FXML
        private void browserBackButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
            if(browserWV.getEngine().getHistory().getCurrentIndex() <= 0) {
                return;
            }
            browserWV.getEngine().getHistory().go(-1);        
        }

        @FXML
        private void browserForwardButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
            if((browserWV.getEngine().getHistory().getCurrentIndex() + 1) >= browserWV.getEngine().getHistory().getEntries().size()) {
                return;
            }
            browserWV.getEngine().getHistory().go(1);
        }

        @FXML
        private void browserGoButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

            String url = addressBarTF.getText().trim();
            /*if(url.isEmpty()) 
            {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No url provided");
                return;
            }
            if(!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")) {
             url = "http://"+url;   
            }*/
            browserWV.getEngine().load(url);
            //browserStopReloadIV.setImage(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/stoploading.png")));


        }





        @FXML
        private void browserStopReloadButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {                
            if(browserWV.getEngine().getLoadWorker().isRunning()) {
                browserWV.getEngine().getLoadWorker().cancel();
                statusL.setText("loaded");
                progressPI.setVisible(false);            
                stopReloadIV.setImage(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/reload.png")));
            } else {            
                browserWV.getEngine().reload();
                stopReloadIV.setImage(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/stoploading.png")));
            }

        }

        @FXML
        private void browserHomeButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
            browserWV.getEngine().loadContent("<html><title>New Tab</title></html>");
            addressBarTF.setText("");        
        }

        private TextField setText(String ur1) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }




    }
```

It's popup class to open new popup window.But when I use window.open method in JavaScript. It's working but in same window.How it will be open in new window?

```
package browser;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.PopupFeatures;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import static sun.plugin.javascript.navig.JSType.URL;

public class popup 
{
   public void open(String url)
    {
    WebView browserWV = new WebView();



    Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
    { 
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        browserWV.getEngine().setCreatePopupHandler(new Callback<PopupFeatures, WebEngine>()
        {

        @Override
        public WebEngine call(PopupFeatures p) {
            Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY);
            WebView wv2 = new WebView();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(wv2));
            stage.show();
            WebEngine webEngine = new WebEngine();
            webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            return wv2.getEngine();
        }
    });
     VBox root = new VBox();
     TextField address_bar = new TextField();
    root.getChildren().add(address_bar);

    root.getChildren().add(browserWV);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1370, 700);

    Stage primaryStage = new Stage();

    primaryStage.setTitle("Popup");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    primaryStage.setIconified(true);


    browserWV.getEngine().load(url);
    address_bar.setText(browserWV.getEngine().getLocation());
    }  

    });
    }
}
```

Comment: File a bug.......

Comment: @Antoniossss Could you please help me to short out this bug?

Comment: Anyone can help?